# Pages with Multiple Versions of JQuery: Can I Select a Specific Version?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on an assignment with a legacy app has multiple versions of jQuery on the page, e.g.,

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.6.js"></script>
```

These aren't in order of oldest to most recent (I don't know what they were doing in the past), and I don't think I have an option or reordering them either.

I have some code that needs to run against the 1.7.2 version. Is there any way to specify which version of jQuery I want to execute my code?

Comment: Why do you need to specifically target 1.7.2?

Comment: My code won't work in the older versions.

Comment: The only way I'm aware of to target a specific version when they're stacked like that is if a different jQuery object has been set for each version. You'd need to check your codebase to see if this is happening.
If you know what parts of your code aren't working, I might be able to help you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @craignewkirk's suggestion, I came up with this solution which works, utilizing the `noConflict()` method:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
  var $x = jQuery.noConflict();
  //alert("Version: "+$x.fn.jquery);
</script>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.6.js"></script>
```

By setting `var $x = jQuery.noConflict();` right after version 1.7.2 load, I can now use `$x` as the 1.7.2 object.